# Получить значений jtable зная строку

Tags: java, swing

есть ли какой-нибудь способ получить значение колонок на определенной строке зная её?

```
final TablePopup tablePopup = new TablePopup(MainJava.jTabPeople);
    MainJava.jTabPeople.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            int row = MainJava.jTabPeople.rowAtPoint(me.getPoint());
            System.out.println("You clicked at column " + row);
            if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                tablePopup.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

значение ячейки таблицы по индексу:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return rowData[row][col]; }
```